# Python to read \n and \r in a txt file

Tags: python, ascii

I have just edited a txt file (file0.txt) with Notepad++ with just clicking the Enter key. That´s it, just one line.

I have reviewed several StackOverflow questions/answers that relate the differences between \r and \n. I have confirmed, even visually on the Notepad++ text editor window, that on a Windows OS, a click on the Enter key introduces two ASCII characters, CRLF(\r\n).

So, why in the world, when I print the line of the previously edited file using this Python 3.4 code:

```
ffile=open('file0.txt')

for line in ffile:
    print(ascii(line))
```

do I get

```
'\n'
```

in the terminal instead of:

```
'\r\n'
```

Comment: If you don't want that behavior you need to open the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes:

```
ffile=open('file0.txt')
```

`open` creates an instance of [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)

```
>>> print(ffile)                                                                                                       
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/asdf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) of [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

> Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are
>   translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller